# How to fix Namespace Laravel selection issue error= '@if(Auth' is not bound

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have this piece of code that I did not write, but need to `trouble shoot`. The user is supposed to have the choice to pick one, two, or all 3 selections, but no matter what we select, nothing is working. It is giving me an error message of `"Namespace '@if(Auth' is not bound"`.

Here is the code that seems to be the root of the problem.

```
 <select id="dates-field2" class="multiselect-ui form-control" multiple="multiple" name="service_type[]" id="service_type">
   @foreach(get_all_service_types() as $type)
      <option @if(Auth::guard('provider')->user()->service->service_type->id == $type->id) selected="selected" @endif value="{{$type->id}}">{{$type->name}}</option>
   @endforeach
 </select>
```

Comment: use slash like `\Auth::guard('provider')->user()->service->service_type->id`

Comment: Or you can use `auth('provider')->user()->service->service_type_id`